# ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost is called multiple time WCF

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a wcf service which hosted at IIS

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyService" Factory="InitializableServiceHostFactory" %>
```

my problem is that the CreateServiceHost is called with each request to MyService method, which make my initialization code which is written in CreateServiceHost is called multiply.

Comment: What is the `InstanceContextMode` of your service?  Also, what are you doing in your initialization code?  Is it expensive, and can you cache it so you only have to do it once?

Comment: InstanceContextMode = PerSession, and may initialization code is expensive and must be ran just one time.

Comment: Is the result of the initialization something you can cache?

Comment: Not there is no result, this initialization code somethings related ioc initialization and another things

Answer (score 2):

After I checked a lot about this problem, I saw that it is related to ASP.NET dynamic compile, it is recompile the whole site when any things inside Bin folder is changed, but my WCF service writes to the temp folder inside Bin folder which make the site recompiled then the Application_Start re-fired, then the InitializableServiceHostFactory re-create the WCF service

I know it is a dummy problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that the service host was not an instance of the service class, and Carlos Figueira confirmed that in his answer to [[Is it necessary to Dispose() when using a custom ServiceHostFactory?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532288/is-it-necessary-to-dispose-when-using-a-custom-servicehostfactory#7533056).

The `CreateServiceHost()` in the factory was being called multiple times for my application, throwing an `ArgumentException` the second time it was initialized, with the message:

```
The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: ....
```

*WCF sometimes reuses the service host*. I worked around the problem by checking if any of my customized behaviors were already in the servicehost's `Description.Endpoints.Behaviors` list, so I didn't initialize my service host a second time. In practice, my case was simpler because I was setting the `ServiceAuthorizationManager`; if I found it set already, I avoided initializing anything again.